# Check rows in pandas dataframe contain particular values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering how to ensure that all rows in a dataframe contain a particular set of values.

For example:

```py
VALUES = [1, 2]
df_no = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1],
        "b": [1],
    }
)
df_yes = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1],
        "b": [2],
        "c": [3],
    }
)
```

Here `df_no` doesn't contain values of `VALUES` in each of its rows, whereas `df_yes` does.

An approach is the following:

```py
# check df_no
all(
    [
        all(value in row for value in VALUES)
        for row in df_no.apply(lambda x: x.unique(), axis=1)
    ]
)
# returns False

# check df_yes 
all(
    [
        all(value in row for value in VALUES)
        for row in df_yes.apply(lambda x: x.unique(), axis=1)
    ]
)

# returns True
```

I feel as though the approaches here might be so clear, and that there might be a more idiomatic way of going about things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `issubset` in generator comprehension:

```
s = set(VALUES)
print (all(s.issubset(x) for x in df_no.to_numpy()))
False


s = set(VALUES)
print (all(s.issubset(x) for x in df_yes.to_numpy()))
True
```

What is faster? Depends of data:

```
VALUES = [1, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1,2,8],
        "b": [2,8,2],
        "c": [3,1,1],
    }
)

#30k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
print (df)


In [171]: %%timeit
     ...: s = set(VALUES)
     ...: all(s.issubset(x) for x in df.to_numpy())
     ...: 
     ...: 
55.9 ms ± 2.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [172]: %%timeit
     ...: vals = set(VALUES)
     ...: df.apply(vals.issubset, axis=1).all()
     ...: 
     ...: 
211 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
#3k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
print (df)



In [174]: %%timeit
     ...: s = set(VALUES)
     ...: all(s.issubset(x) for x in df.to_numpy())
     ...: 
     ...: 
5.46 ms ± 76.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [175]: %%timeit
     ...: vals = set(VALUES)
     ...: df.apply(vals.issubset, axis=1).all()
     ...: 
     ...: 
21.5 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @baxx - It is wrong answer :( Working for correct one.

Comment: @baxx - It not tested each row separately. It tested all data together

Comment: ah of course, yeah it's important that it's each row

Comment: is list comp preferable to apply? I'm not sure if there's any optimisations (or slowness) with apply that I'm unaware of

Comment: now it looks more or less like my answer :(

Comment: @baxx - The best test in real data, `apply` with `axis=1` is obvilusly slow.

Comment: @baxx - What is size of `DataFrame` ?

Comment: varies - I guess a shape of (9, 2000) might be about right for what this is needed for though.

Comment: @baxx - Added some performance timings for `30k` and `3k`, `apply` is slowier here.

Comment: looks like apply is slower for smaller (3K) data and faster for larger? Unless i'm misreading something

Comment: @baxx - No, `apply` are loops under the hood. So if slow in small data, obviously slowier in large data. Especially if `axis=1` in `apply`

Answer (score 1):

You can use python sets and `issubset`:

```
vals = set(VALUES)
df_yes.apply(lambda x: vals.issubset(set(x)), axis=1).all()
```

shorter version:

```
vals = set(VALUES)
df_yes.apply(vals.issubset, axis=1).all()
```