# Ensure each value within a list of values appear only once within each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to ensure that each value within a particular set of values only appears once within each row of a pandas dataframe?

For example:

```py
VALUES = [1, 2]
df_no = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2],
        "b": [1, 2],
    }
)
df_yes = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2],
        "b": [2, 4],
        "c": [3, 1],
    }
)
```

The following works:

```py
def check(data, values):
    for row in data.itertuples(index=False):
        row_values = [x for x in row if x in values]
        if len(row_values) != len(set(row_values)):
            return False
        return True


check(data=df_no, values=VALUES) # False
check(data=df_yes, values=VALUES) # True
```

I feel there's a cleaner approach though, `itertuples` feels like a warning signal.

Answer (score 2):

Idea is compare `dicts` from `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

s = set(Counter(VALUES).items())
x = all(s.issubset(Counter(x).items()) for x in df_no.to_numpy())
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2],
        "b": [2, 1],
        "c": [1, 2],
        "d": [2, 1],
    }
)

from collections import Counter

s = set(Counter(VALUES).items())
x = all(s.issubset(Counter(x).items()) for x in df.to_numpy())
print (x)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a variation on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68906886/16343464):

```
from collections import Counter
vals = set(VALUES)
all(Counter(e for e in x if e in vals).most_common()[0][1]<2 for x in df.to_numpy())
```

or using apply:

```
from collections import Counter
vals = set(VALUES)
df.apply(lambda x: Counter(e for e in x if e in vals).most_common()[0][1]<2, axis=1).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the length of the sets are all equal to the number of columns in your df.

```
def check(data):
    return data.apply(set, axis=1).apply(lambda x: len(x)==data.shape[1]).all()
```